# Image segmentation in android using mask R-CNN

Tags: android, kotlin, mask-rcnn

Is it possible to implement Mask R-CNN for background removal in android kotlin? I know that it is possible to use GrabCut in android but I need to use both of these algorithms. I am planning to use Mask R-CNN to automatically detect the object and do the initial segmentation and use GrabCut to clean the remaining background that is segmented by Mask R-CNN.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to implement yourself the r-cnn algorithm in kotlin? Of course it is possible, but I have the feeling that's not exactly what you actually want, maybe rephrase your question to be clearer on what you want.